# Event caller doesn't appear to be working

Tags: javascript, json, object, dictionary

I am a beginner in programming so don't be too hard on me if I have asked this question wrong or if this problem has a really simple solution. StackOverflow is my last resort.

The chemical symbol doesn't show up, I am pretty sure that it is a problem with my event caller but can't be sure. I also doubt my if statements are correct.

I have left the code below, it would be great if you'd be able to point out other issues or possible improvements as well.

[Code and question have been updated]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculating Moles</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//All elements, 
//their chemical symbols, relative atomic masses and valences. 
//Sorted by relative atomic mass and/or valency.

var elements_obj =
            {"elements": [
            {name: "Hydrogen", symbol: "H", ram: 1.00794, valency: 1},
            {name: "Helium", symbol: "He", ram: 4.002602, valency: 1},
            {name: "Lithium", symbol: "Li", ram: 6.941, valency: 2},
            {name: "Beryllium", symbol: "Be", ram: 9.012182, valency: 2},
            {name: "Boron", symbol: "B", ram: 10.811, valency: 2},
            {name: "Carbon", symbol: "C", ram: 12.0107, valency: 2},
            {name: "Nitrogen", symbol: "N", ram: 14.0067, valency: 2},
            {name: "Oxygen", symbol: "O", ram: 15.9994, valency: 2},
            {name: "Fluorine", symbol: "F", ram: 18.9984032, valency: 2},
            {name: "Neon", symbol: "Ne", ram: 20.1797, valency: 2},
            {name: "Sodium", symbol: "Na", ram: 22.98976928, valency: 3},
            {name: "Magnesium", symbol: "Mg", ram: 24.3050, valency: 3},
            {name: "Aluminium", symbol: "Al", ram: 26.9815386, valency: 3},
            {name: "Silicon", symbol: "Si", ram: 28.0855, valency: 3},
            {name: "Phosphorus", symbol: "P", ram: 30.973762, valency: 3},
            {name: "Sulfur", symbol: "S", ram: 32.065, valency: 3},
            {name: "Chlorine", symbol: "Cl", ram: 35.453, valency: 3},
            {name: "Argon", symbol: "Ar", ram: 39.948, valency: 3},
            {name: "Potassium", symbol: "K", ram: 39.0983, valency: 4},
            {name: "Calcium", symbol: "Ca", ram: 40.078, valency: 4},
            {name: "Scandium", symbol: "Sc", ram: 44.955912, valency: 4},
            {name: "Titanium", symbol: "Ti", ram: 47.867, valency: 4},
            {name: "Vanadium", symbol: "V", ram: 50.9415, valency: 4},
            {name: "Chromium", symbol: "Cr", ram: 51.9961, valency: 4},
            {name: "Manganese", symbol: "Mn", ram: 54.938045, valency: 4},
            {name: "Iron", symbol: "Fe", ram: 55.845, valency: 4},
            {name: "Cobalt", symbol: "Co", ram: 58.933195, valency: 4},
            {name: "Nickel", symbol: "Ni", ram: 58.6934, valency: 4},
            {name: "Copper", symbol: "Cu", ram: 63.546, valency: 4},
            {name: "Zinc", symbol: "Zn", ram: 65.39, valency: 4},
            {name: "Gallium", symbol: "Ga", ram: 69.723, valency: 4},
            {name: "Germanium", symbol: "Ge", ram: 72.64, valency: 4},
            {name: "Arsenic", symbol: "As", ram: 74.92160, valency: 4},
            {name: "Selenium", symbol: "Se", ram: 78.96, valency: 4},
            {name: "Bromine", symbol: "Br", ram: 79.904, valency: 4},
            {name: "Krypton", symbol: "Kr", ram: 83.798, valency: 4},
            {name: "Rubidium", symbol: "Rb", ram: 85.4678, valency: 5},
            {name: "Strontium", symbol: "Sr", ram: 87.62, valency: 5},
            {name: "Yttrium", symbol: "Y", ram: 88.90585, valency: 5},
            {name: "Zirconium", symbol: "Zr", ram: 91.224, valency: 5},
            {name: "Niobium", symbol: "Nb", ram: 92.906, valency: 5},
            {name: "Molybdenum", symbol: "Mo", ram: 95.94, valency: 5},
            {name: "Technetium", symbol: "Tc", ram: 97.9072, valency: 5},
            {name: "Ruthenium", symbol: "Ru", ram: 101.07, valency: 5},
            {name: "Rhodium", symbol: "Rh", ram: 102.905, valency: 5},
            {name: "Palladium", symbol: "Pd", ram: 106.42, valency: 5},
            {name: "Silver", symbol: "Ag", ram: 107.8682, valency: 5},
            {name: "Cadmium", symbol: "Cd", ram: 112.411, valency: 5},
            {name: "Indium", symbol: "In", ram: 114.818, valency: 5},
            {name: "Tin", symbol: "Sn", ram: 118.710, valency: 5},
            {name: "Antimony", symbol: "Sb", ram: 121.760, valency: 5},
            {name: "Tellurium", symbol: "Te", ram: 127.60, valency: 5},
            {name: "Iodine", symbol: "I", ram: 126.904, valency: 5},
            {name: "Xenon", symbol: "Xe", ram: 131.293, valency: 5},
            {name: "Caesium", symbol: "Cs", ram: 132.9054519, valency: 6},
            {name: "Barium", symbol: "Ba", ram: 137.327, valency: 6},
            {name: "Lanthanum", symbol: "La", ram: 138.90547, valency: 6},
            {name: "Cerium", symbol: "Ce", ram: 140.116, valency: 6},
            {name: "Praseodymium", symbol: "Pr", ram: 140.90765, valency: 6},
            {name: "Neodymium", symbol: "Nd", ram: 144.242, valency: 6},
            {name: "Promethium", symbol: "Pm", ram: 144.9127, valency: 6},
            {name: "Samarium", symbol: "Sm", ram: 150.36, valency: 6},
            {name: "Europium", symbol: "Eu", ram: 151.964, valency: 6},
            {name: "Gadolinium", symbol: "Gd", ram: 157.25, valency: 6},
            {name: "Terbium", symbol: "Tb", ram: 158.92535, valency: 6},
            {name: "Dysprosium", symbol: "Dy", ram: 162.500, valency: 6},
            {name: "Holmium", symbol: "Ho", ram: 164.930, valency: 6},
            {name: "Erbium", symbol: "Er", ram: 167.259, valency: 6},
            {name: "Thulium", symbol: "Tm", ram: 168.93421, valency: 6},
            {name: "Ytterbium", symbol: "Yb", ram: 173.04, valency: 6},
            {name: "Lutetium", symbol: "Lu", ram: 174.967, valency: 6},
            {name: "Hafnium", symbol: "Hf", ram: 178.49, valency: 6},
            {name: "Tantalum", symbol: "Ta", ram: 180.94788, valency: 6},
            {name: "Tungsten", symbol: "W", ram: 183.84, valency: 6},
            {name: "Rhenium", symbol: "Re", ram: 186.207, valency: 6},
            {name: "Osmium", symbol: "Os", ram: 190.23, valency: 6},
            {name: "Iridium", symbol: "Ir", ram: 192.217, valency: 6},
            {name: "Platinum", symbol: "Pt", ram: 195.084, valency: 6},
            {name: "Gold", symbol: "Au", ram: 196.966569, valency: 6},
            {name: "Mercury", symbol: "Hg", ram: 200.59, valency: 6},
            {name: "Thallium", symbol: "Tl", ram: 204.3833, valency: 6},
            {name: "Lead", symbol: "Pb", ram: 207.2, valency: 6},
            {name: "Bismuth", symbol: "Bi", ram: 208.98040, valency: 6},
            {name: "Polonium", symbol: "Po", ram: 208.9824, valency: 6},
            {name: "Astatine", symbol: "At", ram: 209.9871, valency: 6},
            {name: "Radon", symbol: "Rn", ram: 222.0176, valency: 6},
            {name: "Francium", symbol: "Fr", ram: 223.0197, valency: 7},
            {name: "Radium", symbol: "Ra", ram: 226.0254, valency: 7},
            {name: "Actinium", symbol: "Ac", ram: 227.0277, valency: 7},
            {name: "Thorium", symbol: "Th", ram: 232.03806, valency: 7},
            {name: "Protactinium", symbol: "Pa", ram: 231.03588, valency: 7},
            {name: "Uranium", symbol: "U", ram: 238.02891, valency: 7},
            {name: "Neptunium", symbol: "Np", ram: 237.0482, valency: 7},
            {name: "Plutonium", symbol: "Pu", ram: 244.0642, valency: 7},
            {name: "Americium", symbol: "Am", ram: 243.0614, valency: 7},
            {name: "Curium", symbol: "Cm", ram: 247.0704, valency: 7},
            {name: "Berkelium", symbol: "Bk", ram: 247.0703, valency: 7},
            {name: "Californium", symbol: "Cf", ram: 251.0796, valency: 7},
            {name: "Einsteinium", symbol: "Es", ram: 252.0830, valency: 7},
            {name: "Fermium", symbol: "Fm", ram: 257.0951, valency: 7},
            {name: "Mendelevium", symbol: "Md", ram: 258.0984, valency: 7},
            {name: "Nobelium", symbol: "No", ram: 259.1010, valency: 7},
            {name: "Lawrencium", symbol: "Lr", ram: 262.1097, valency: 7},
            {name: "Rutherfordium", symbol: "Rf", ram: 261.1088, valency: 7},
            {name: "Dubnium", symbol: "Db", ram: 262, valency: 7},
            {name: "Seaborgium", symbol: "Sg", ram: 266, valency: 7},
            {name: "Bohrium", symbol: "Bh", ram: 264, valency: 7},
            {name: "Hassium", symbol: "Hs", ram: 277, valency: 7},
            {name: "Meitnerium", symbol: "Mt", ram: 268, valency: 7},
            {name: "Darmstadtium", symbol: "Ds", ram: 271, valency: 7},
            {name: "Roentgenium", symbol: "Rg", ram: 272, valency: 7},
            {name: "Ununbium", symbol: "Uub", ram: 285, valency: 7},
            {name: "Ununtrium", symbol: "Uut", ram: 284, valency: 7},
            {name: "Ununquadium", symbol: "Uuq", ram: 289, valency: 7},
            {name: "Ununpentium", symbol: "Uup", ram: 288, valency: 7},
            {name: "Ununhexium", symbol: "Uuh", ram: 292, valency: 7},
            {name: "Ununseptium", symbol: "Uus", ram: "Not Applicable", valency: 7},
            {name: "Ununoctium", symbol: "Uuo", ram: 294, valency: 7}]};

var elementNumbers = {
    "Hydrogen": 1,
    "Helium": 2,
    "Lithium": 3,
    "Beryllium": 4,
    "Boron": 5,
    "Carbon": 6,
    "Nitrogen": 7,
    "Oxygen": 8,
    "Fluorine": 9,
    "Neon": 10,
    "Sodium": 11,
    "Magnesium": 12,
    "Aluminum": 13,
    "Silicon": 14,
    "Phosphorus": 15,
    "Sulfur": 16,
    "Chlorine": 17,
    "Argon": 18,
    "Potassium": 19,
    "Calcium": 20,
    "Scandium": 21,
    "Titanium": 22,
    "Vanadium": 23,
    "Chromium": 24,
    "Manganese": 25,
    "Iron": 26,
    "Cobalt": 27,
    "Nickel": 28,
    "Copper": 29,
    "Zinc": 30,
    "Gallium": 31,
    "Germanium": 32,
    "Arsenic": 33,
    "Selenium": 34,
    "Bromine": 35,
    "Krypton": 36,
    "Rubidium": 37,
    "Strontium": 38,
    "Yttrium": 39,
    "Zirconium": 40,
    "Niobium": 41,
    "Molybdenum": 42,
    "Technetium": 43,
    "Ruthenium": 44,
    "Rhodium": 45,
    "Palladium": 46,
    "Silver": 47,
    "Cadmium": 48,
    "Indium": 49,
    "Tin": 50,
    "Antimony": 51,
    "Tellurium": 52,
    "Iodine": 53,
    "Xenon": 54,
    "Cesium": 55,
    "Barium": 56,
    "Lanthanum": 57,
    "Cerium": 58,
    "Praseodymium": 59,
    "Neodymium": 60,
    "Promethium": 61,
    "Samarium": 62,
    "Europium": 63,
    "Gadolinium": 64,
    "Terbium": 65,
    "Dysprosium": 66,
    "Holmium": 67,
    "Erbium": 68,
    "Thulium": 69,
    "Ytterbium": 70,
    "Lutetium": 71,
    "Hafnium": 72,
    "Tantalum": 73,
    "Tungsten": 74,
    "Rhenium": 75,
    "Osmium": 76,
    "Iridium": 77,
    "Platinum": 78,
    "Gold": 79,
    "Mercury": 80,
    "Thallium": 81,
    "Lead": 82,
    "Bismuth": 83,
    "Polonium": 84,
    "Astatine": 85,
    "Radon": 86,
    "Francium": 87,
    "Radium": 88,
    "Actinium": 89,
    "Thorium": 90,
    "Protactinium": 91,
    "Uranium": 92,
    "Neptunium": 93,
    "Plutonium": 94,
    "Americium": 95,
    "Curium": 96,
    "Berkelium": 97,
    "Californium": 98,
    "Einsteinium": 99,
    "Fermium": 100,
    "Mendelevium": 101,
    "Nobelium": 102,
    "Lawrencium": 103,
    "Rutherfordium": 104,
    "Dubnium": 105,
    "Seaborgium": 106,
    "Bohrium": 107,
    "Hassium": 108,
    "Meitnerium": 109,
    "Darmstadtium": 110,
    "Roentgenium": 111,
    "Ununbium": 112,
    "Ununtrium": 113,
    "Ununquadium": 114,
    "Ununpentium": 115,
    "Ununhexium": 116,
    "Ununseptium": 117,
    "Ununoctium": 118
};

function findNumber(elementName) {
    "use strict";
    var elementNumber = elementNumbers[elementName];
    return elementNumber - 1;
}

//Runs when the user clicks Calculate
function calculate() {
    "use strict";

    var element1 = document.getElementById('first_Element').innerHTML,
        element2 = document.getElementById('second_Element').innerHTML,
        elementNumber = findNumber(element1),
        //Finds element's symbol abbreviation
        symbol = elements_obj.elements[elementNumber].symbol,
        //Finds the element's valency
        valency = elements_obj.elements[elementNumber].valency,
        //Creates variables for Relative Atomic Mass and Valences
        ram = elements_obj.elements[elementNumber].ram,
        subnum = valency,
        //Calculates number of moles
        moles =  " " + (ram * valency);

    //When the first box has a value and the second does not
    if (element1 != "" && element2 == "") {

        //Displays symbol, valency and number of moles
        document.getElementById('symbol').innerHTML = symbol;
        document.getElementById('subnum').innerHTML = "<sub>" + subnum + "</sub>";
        document.getElementById('moles').innerHTML = moles;
    } else if (element1 != "" && element2 != "") {
        //To Be Added for when the first box has a value and so does the second box
    } else {
        //Displays error message when the user doesn't enter an element
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'ERROR: Please enter a value in at least the first box.';
    }
}
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>
        Mole Calculator
        </h1>

        <p>
        Enter the names of the two elements you would like the calculator to evaluate.<br>
        Remember to capitalize the first letter of the name of your element/s.
        <!--Could be changed afterwards using JavaScript to make everything lowercase, but I am just using this for simplicity right now-->
        </p>

        <p>
        Element 1: <input type="text" id="first_Element">
        (optional) Element 2: <input type="text" id="second_Element">

        <input value="Calculate" type="button" onclick="calculate()">
        </p>

        <div id="error"></div>

        <p>
        Chemical Symbol: <div id="symbol"></div><div id="subnum"></div>
        Number of Moles: <div id="moles" style="display:inline;"></div><div style="display:inline;"> grams</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you storing a *JSON string* in your JavaScript code?!

Comment: It was suggested by a friend, I don't really understand how it helps @poke

Comment: @jacklouisirvine JSON is typically pulled from somewhere externally and parsed to be handled by your code. If you want standard object literals, you can use the notation described [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28254078/3366929) by Ben.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you do not need to use JSON, but can use an object literal.

```
var elements =
    { 
      "elements": [
        { "name": "Hydrogen", "symbol": "H", "ram": 1.00794, "valency": 1 },
        { "name": "Helium", "symbol": "He", "ram": 4.002602, "valency": 1 }
       ]
    };

// Usage...
var hydrogen = elements.elements[0];
```

If you want to pull the data into a separate file later as JSON is is trivial (copy paste the value of `elements` above into a file). You would then need to read the file and use `JSON.parse`.

Or simpler:

```
var elements = [
        { name: "Hydrogen", symbol: "H", ram: 1.00794, valency: 1 },
        { name: "Helium", symbol: "He", ram: 4.002602, valency: 1 }
       ];

// Usage...
var hydrogen = elements[0];
```

Fixing this may solve your problem.

Recommend cutting out information from your question that is not directly relevant.

Comment: I had this before a friend recommended turning it into a JSON string

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't fix the problem of it not displaying the symbol on the page @Ben

Comment: I have updated the code to match your suggestions. @Ben